# how to exclude last td from table-layout

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a table with dynamic rows. When I add new row appears delete button. I use `table-layout` and when delete button appears this button size becomes like another td sizes. I try to add table width and this 'delete button' width (`table table-layout:fixed; width:100%`) but it not works, then I try to set width to button (`width:5%`) and again not works. `table-layout` so comfortable and I don't wanna to remove this property, but I have problem with it, where I'm wrong? [Here is my Plnkr example..](https://plnkr.co/edit/Esp47nA6Jksbeq7Jxi9j?p=preview)

UPD. I have table with `table-layout` and dynamic rows, at first screen displays default view
[image]
When I add new row I add "remove button". This button should be small but because `table-layout` 'remove button' the same width with another rows:
[image]

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, and the Plunkr doesn't load here, so I'm not sure what the problem is. Can you rephrase the question a bit, and add a stacksnippet?

Comment: It's weird couse I check plnkr and it works.. anyway I upd my question :)

Comment: Oh, I was using NoScript, and apparently it clashed with Plunkr, even when I disabled it. OK. Well, that's how table-layout:fixed works: the first row determines the widths of the table cells. If you want the last column to be 30px wide, add an extra th to the thead. Then the table will know there are 5 columns, and you can style the last one. See [updated Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Y3owOO5oFKtSzOFG5HO3?p=preview).

Comment: thx for help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is about the style of the last column containing the delete button, I may suggest you to add in your css:

```
table, tr, td:nth-child(-1) {
     width: auto;
     border:none;
     margin: 1px;
}
```

The updated [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/NBt4hi2983RzxcxRfual?p=preview)

Comment: thx! but columns load dynamic too, so I can't say how many columns will be. I guess I can change `td:nth-child(5)` to `td:last-child` but it crush 1st row...

Comment: @YoroDiallo  If you do not know how many cells do you have per row you may use nth-child(-1): the last one. Answer updated. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```js
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.item = [
       {
         field : [
            {
              name : 'Bird',
              id : 'littleBird',
              value : 'Dove'
            },
            {
              name : 'Dog',
              id : 'bigGreyDog',
              value : 'Lucky'
            },
            {
              name : 'Cat',
              id : 'tinyKitty',
              value : 'Fluffy'
            },
            {
              name : 'Bug',
              id : 'uglyBug',
              value : 'Buggy'
            }
           ]
       }
      ]
      
  $scope.addRow = function() {
    var copy = angular.copy($scope.item[0]);
    $scope.item.push(copy)
  }
  
  $scope.removeRow = function(index) {
    $scope.item.splice(index, 1)
  }
})
```

```css
.delete{width: 100%;}
.deleteparent{border:none;}
table{border:none;}
table thead th{border:1px solid #ccc;border-collapse:collapse !important;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='App'>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller='Ctrl'>
    <h1>table</h1>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th ng-repeat='item in item[0].field'>{{item.name}}</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      
      <tbody ng-form='tableForm'>
        <tr ng-repeat='row in item'>
          <td ng-repeat='field in row.field'>
            <input type="text"
                   ng-model='field.value' 
                   name='{{field.id}}'
                   required
                   ng-class='{"is-invalid": tableForm[field.id].$invalid}'>
          </td>
          <td ng-if='$index !== 0' class="deleteparent"
              ><button style='color:red;cursor:pointer'
              ng-click='removeRow($index)' class="delete">X</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <button ng-click='addRow()'>add row</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking. Instead of adding another visible column in the table, make it appear as if the delete column isn't actually part of, and doesn't affect the width of, the table.

Comment: can u share your expected design screen shot or image